# Recursive binary searching function doesn't return -1 for value that's not existant in the array

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search

I'm trying to do a binary sorting function using recursion. It works well with the values that exist in the `list[]` structure array. However, when I punch in a value that I know is not inside the array, instead of returning -1, it returns garbage value. I traced the code using debugger in MVS but there might be (in fact, definitely is) something that I just can't see.

Can somebody tell me why it doesn't return -1?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 20

typedef struct
{
    char name[MAX] = "";
    char surname[MAX] = "";
    int id;
}patient;

int binarySearch(patient list[], char *target, int top, int bottom, int *comparisons)
{
    int center;
    center = (top + bottom) / 2;
    if (strcmp(list[center].surname, target) == 0)
        return center;
    (*comparisons)++;

    if (top == center || bottom == center)
        return -1;
    if (strcmp(list[center].surname, target) == 1)
        return binarySearch(list, target, center - 1, bottom, comparisons);
    if (strcmp(list[center].surname, target) == -1)
        return binarySearch(list, target, top, center + 1, comparisons);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fi = fopen("patients.txt", "r");

    if (fi == NULL)
        printf("Problem opening file!");
    else
    {
        patient list[MAX];
        int i = 0, comparisons = 0, index;
        char target[MAX] = "";

        while (fscanf(fi, "%s %s %d", &list[i].name, &list[i].surname, &list[i].id) != EOF)
            i++;

        printf("Enter the surname of the patient (END to exit): ");
        scanf("%s", target);

        index = binarySearch(list, target, i, 0, &comparisons);

        printf("%-15s %-15s %-15d\n", list[index].name, list[index].surname, list[index].id);
        printf("%d comparisons\n", comparisons);

    }
}
```

Comment: As so often, you must provide an MCVE. Please see the site guidelines for further info on what's on-topic or off-topic.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hello. I assumed the question to be somewhat MCVE to be honest but I totally can be wrong. Would you kindly please point out your suggestion to make it more suitable so I can provide ASAP?

Comment: To be an MCVE, people should be able to compile and run what you've provided and have the output confirm your stated problem.  As it stands, I would have to guess at what you did to drive this and write more code to run it.

Comment: @pjs Oh. I thought posting the entire code would be wasteful. Let me update the question.

Comment: Don't just dump your code here. The example is supposed be be minimal but at the same time complete. It's actually required that you first remove the irrelevant parts.

Comment: Depends on what "the entire code" is.  The "minimal" part of MCVE is providing just enough to illustrate the problem in a self-contained chunk of code.

Answer (score 4):

You get a garbage value because your conditionals at the end are non-exhaustive.

When `strcmp` indicates that the first value is after the second value, is not required to return `1`. The only requirement is that it returns a positive number. Same goes for less then and negative one `-1`. Therefore, your function may end up reaching the end without hitting `return`, which is undefined behavior.

You need to change your chain of `if`s to compare return values with zero. As an optimization, you should store comparison result once, and reuse it throughout your conditionals:

```
int binarySearch(patient list[], char *target, int top, int bottom, int *comparisons)
{
    int center = (top + bottom) / 2;
    (*comparisons)++;
    int cmp = strcmp(list[center].surname, target);
    if (cmp == 0)
        return center;
    if (top == center || bottom == center)
        return -1;
    if (cmp > 0)
        return binarySearch(list, target, center - 1, bottom, comparisons);
    else // cmp < 0 here
        return binarySearch(list, target, top, center + 1, comparisons);
}
```

Also note that in order to account for the number of comparisons in an accurate way, `(*comparisons)++` should happen before `strcmp` call.

Comment: Thank you. That definitely was an improvement on top of the code! However, problem still persists after updating the function.

Comment: @SarpSTA It works perfectly for me ([demo](https://ideone.com/Vy7B0s)).

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into it more, try to find the problem on my own. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SarpSTA Just to make sure, your `"patients.txt"` file is sorted alphabetically, right?

Comment: Yes. It is ordered by the last names in alphabetical order

Answer (score 1):

How to save time:  1) ensure compiler warnings are fully enabled.  2) Use a good compiler.

I'd expect the below to to generate a warning like " warning: control reaches end of non-void function",  providing you good and faster feedback than stack-overflow.

```
  if (strcmp(list[center].surname, target) == -1)
    return binarySearch(list, target, top, center + 1, comparisons);
}
```

---

Other good compiler feedback  `"error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '='"`

```
typedef struct {
  char name[MAX] = "";  // not valid to initialize.
```

"traced the code using debugger in MVS" --> leads me to wonder if you are compiling your C code as C++ code.

Comment: Why is `char name[MAX] = "";` not valid?

Comment: @SarpSTA `char name[MAX] = "";` is valid by itself.  It is not valid as part of a `typedef`.  What C compiler are you using?

Comment: Whichever it is that comes with MVS2017. Might be a C++ compiler as you mentioned.